# Sum table values ​per day

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table as shown in the image, where each comment has a publication date, with year, month, day and time, I would like to add the sentiment values ​​by day.

[image]

this is how the table is composed

`serie <- data.frame(comments$created_time,sentiment2$positive-sentiment2$negative)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(as.Date(comments.created_time)) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(sentiment))
```

Here is some sample data that will help others to troubleshoot and understand the data:

```
df <- tibble(comments.created_time = c("2015-01-26 22:43:00",
                                       "2015-01-26 22:44:00",
                                       "2015-01-27 22:43:00",
                                       "2015-01-27 22:44:00",
                                       "2015-01-28 22:43:00",
                                       "2015-01-28 22:44:00"),
             sentiment = c(1,3,5,1,9,1))
```

Using the sample data will yield:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  `as.Date(comments.created_time)` total
  <date>                           <dbl>
1 2015-01-26                           4
2 2015-01-27                           6
3 2015-01-28                          10
```

Comment: I tried to use your formula `library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(as.Date(comments.created_time)) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(sentiment))`   however it gives me this error here: `Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: I have over a million dates, so it's not feasible to use the second combine formula

Comment: You should still be able to use this solution with 1m rows. I'm not sure why you're getting the error - did you change `df` to be the name of your `data.frame`?

Comment: ok i solved, where to change `df`, thanks a lot

Comment: No problem -  you can click the green checkmark to accept the answer if it solved your question.